# change attrib name with array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with this input:

```
<input id="cant_user" type="text" name="cant_user" value="1" onblur="addInputs()">
```

`#userData` is cloned  when add a input value greater than 1 and I want to change input name from `user_age` to `age[n]`

```
<div id="userData">
    <div class="panel-body" id="generated[0]">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Age User [n]</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="user_age[]" value="0" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function addInputs() {
  var cantUsers = document.getElementById("cant_user").value;
  var countGenerated = $('[id^=generated]').length;
  if (countGenerated > 0) {
    $('[id^=generated]').not(':first').remove();
  }
  if (cantUsers != 1) {
    if (cantUsers > 1 && cantUsers < 10) {
      for (var i = 1; i < cantUsers; i++) {
        jQuery("#userData").append(jQuery("#userData").children().first().clone());
        jQuery("#userData").children().last().attr("id", "generated[" + i + "]");

        for (var n = 0; n <= i; m++) {
          var u = document.getElementsByName("user_age[]");
          $(u).removeAttr("name").attr({
            id: "generatedAge[" + n + "]",
            name: "age[" + n + "]"
          });
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

How can I make every label and input name shows a value from array like:

```
<label>Age User 1<label>
<input name="age[0]">
<label>Age User 2<label>
<input name="age[1]">
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How can i make every label and input name shows a value from array like:

    <label>Age User 1<label>
    <input name="age[0]">
    <label>Age User 2<label>
    <input name="age[1]">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some code, it maybe can help if i understand your idea correct

```
for ( var i = 1; i < cantUsers; i++) {
var userData = jQuery("#userData");
var childOfUserData = userData.children();
userData.append( childOfUserData.first().clone() ); 

childOfUserData = userData.children(); //because we just appen new data
childOfUserData.last().attr("id","generated[" + i + "]");
for ( var n = 0; n <= i; n++ ) {
    var child =  childOfUserData.get(i);
    var userAge = $("input", $(child));//because you only have one input
    userAge.attr("name","age[" + n + "]").attr("id","generatedAge[" + n + "]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input name="age[0]">`

In the above code `name` attribute value acts as text not an array value.

To get an array value in the `attribute`, you need to change the `JavaScript` code

`$("#userData").children().last().attr("id", generated[i]);`

`$(u).removeAttr("name").attr({
   id: generatedAge[n],
   name: age[n]
 });`

Now, if you check the attribute value, you will receive data into it.

Hope this will help you.